# How to create dynamic menulets in OSX

Tags: macos, menubar

I want to put a dynamically generated icon (not static image) + possibly a tiny bit of text in OSX menu bar.

If possible I'd prefer to do it from Ruby or some other convenient scripting language, but I'll deal with Objective C if that's the only way.

How do I do that?

Comment: http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.24/24.07/NSStatusitem/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at MacRuby: virtually everything you can do from Obj-C you can also do from MacRuby.

As for details, look for an Obj-C tutorial, and work from that.

Oh, and the term you will need to use is NSStatusItem.

Comment: MacRuby doesn't have 10.5 binaries, and won't compile against version of llvm from MacPorts. Why such problems happen all the time on OSX, and never on any Linux?

(but I figured out some RubyCocoa hack for it)